# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid date format

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, time, date-format

Below is the function to check that current date-time is lower than specified date-time :

```
  bool isUpcomingCurrentTimeIsAfter(String strDateToCompare) {
  bool returnType=false;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a').format(now);
  DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse(strDateToCompare);
  String targetedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a').format(dt2);

  if(formattedDate.compareTo(targetedDate) == 0){
    returnType=true;
  }

  if(formattedDate.compareTo(targetedDate) < 0){
    returnType=true;
  }

  if(formattedDate.compareTo(targetedDate) > 0){
    returnType=false;
  }
  return returnType;
}
```

Calling this function as below :

```
if (!isUpcomingCurrentTimeIsAfter(
                    eventDate[0] + " " + convertedTime)) {
```

and getting below exception :

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid date format
> E/flutter (14848): 2022-10-07 06:04 AM
> E/flutter (14848): #0      DateTime.parse (dart:core/date_time.dart:347:7)
> E/flutter (14848): #1      isUpcomingCurrentTimeIsAfter (package:mahotsav/src/utils/date_utils.dart:328:27)

What might be the issue?

Comment: Can you include passed data on `isUpcomingCurrentTimeIsAfter`

Comment: 2022-10-07 06:04 AM

Comment: Is it ok if I use other approach which will only work with this format ?

Comment: ya sure. please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I am creating custom format, as I've mentioned on comment, it will only work on question format string.

```dart
bool isAfterToday(String strDateToCompare) {
  //  "2022-10-07 06:04 AM";
  final data = strDateToCompare.split(" ");
  bool isPM = data.last.toLowerCase() == "pm";
  int hour = int.tryParse(data[1].split(":").first) ?? 0;

  if (isPM) hour += 12;
  String min = data[1].split(":").last.padLeft(2, "0");

  //* converting format to `2012-02-27 13:27:00`
  final refined = "${data.first} ${hour.toString().padLeft(2, "0")}:$min:00";
  DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse(refined);

  return DateTime.now().isAfter(dt2); // add logic based your case
}
```

I think it would be better to store and compare  [`toIso8601String`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/toIso8601String.html)

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you are passing a non supported format to the function *DateTime.parse*.

Take a look at [the official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html) for the supported formats.

Comment: Tell me the solution please.

Comment: I already told you. You must use a supported format